# Java JSON object to read a list value

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a JSON response something like this:

```
{
  "id_list":["123", "456", "789"],
  ...
}
```

I was wondering what I should do if I want use the JSONObject to read such a id list and to return a `List<String>` of the ids for example. I did not see there's any method in JSONObject can do such thing (ref: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html). The most possible one might be the `JSONArray`, but I don't know if I use `JSONArray` and turn every value in the list to be an `JSONObject`, how can I read them without keys.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the JSONArray and store each value to the list, and return that.

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonString); //
JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("id_list"); // get the JSONArray
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
    keys.add(ja.getString(i)); // iterate the JSONArray and extract the keys
}

return keys; // return the list
```